Do clubs have an obligation to play in the Fifa Club World Cup?
Reading about the somewhat muted reception in parts of the world to the expanded FIFA Club World Cup I am wondering what is stopping an uninterested club from not going?
...other than money.

The rules are yet to be set/announced, but it is expected that withdrawals will be fined about 500,000€

But what are the agreements in place that allow FIFA to do that? For example Chelsea will be playing in a tournement that they technically qualified for over four years before the start next year, and this'll be the second time they have qualified for the FCWC by winning the '21 CL. Whats stopping them saying 'no we'll have our summer break thank you'. I am not suggesting that Chelsea are uninterested btw.

That's part of being a member of a FIFA association, like the FA for Chelsea or any other national association. You have to agree to the rules they dump on you.
